# emacs-25: mailcap settings for dired-view-file

Tags: dired

I like to view pdf file in a dired buffer using xpdf. The following code in my ~/.emacs works fine for emacs-24. Just hitting "v" launches the xpdf with file (I stipulated xpdf in my ~/.mailcap file).

```
(autoload 'mailcap-parse-mailcaps "mailcap" nil t)
(autoload 'mm-mailcap-command "mm-decode")
(defadvice dired-view-file (around use-mailcap-mime-data activate)
"Use an external viewer to view a file according to `mailcap-mime-data'."
(unless (let ((file (dired-get-file-for-visit))
extension type command)
(and (not (file-directory-p file))
(progn
(mailcap-parse-mailcaps)
(setq extension (file-name-extension file)))
(setq type (mailcap-extension-to-mime extension))
(setq command (mailcap-mime-info type))
(setq command (mm-mailcap-command command file nil))
(prog1
t
(shell-command command))))
ad-do-it))
```

However it stopped working with emacs-25 (emacs-25.0.5.11) with the error

```
mm-mailcap-command: Wrong type argument: stringp, doc-view-mode
```

Of course I can run xpdf via a shell command, but I am curious why emacs-25 does not seem to parse mailcaps. I haven't found any answers on the emacs-devel forums.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to decode a pdf file to open it?  Why not just open it directly with the pdf viewer using `start-process` and `dired-get-file-for-visit`?  I am having difficulty understanding why `mailcap`, `mime`, etc. are involved in this scenario ...?  None of that `mailcap` stuff should be needed to open a pdf file.

Comment: @lawlist IIUC, he has a general command for opening files which uses mailcap to decide what command to use on each file. It seems to have stopped working specifically on pdfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What's happening

The reason this is happening is that the `mailcap-mime-data`
variable includes an entry for `docview-mode` and another for `xpdf`:

```
(defvar mailcap-mime-data
  `(("application"
     ;; snip
     ("pdf"
      (viewer . doc-view-mode)
      (type . "application/pdf")
      (test . (eq window-system 'x)))
     ("pdf"
      (viewer . "xpdf %s")
      (type . "application/pdf")
      ("print" . ,(concat "pdftops %s - | " mailcap-print-command))
      (test . (eq window-system 'x)))
     ;; snip
     )))
```

Both entries are viable on your system, and the function
`mailcap-viewer-lessp` then decides that `doc-view-mode` is
prefereable to `xpdf`.

However, note how the `viewer` entry there is a symbol, not a string.
Whereas the advice you're using assumes that the `viewer` is a string
(shell-command).

#### How to fix

One way to work around your problem is to remove the `docview` entry
from `mailcap-mime-data` (you may also have to remove other non-xpdf
entries). But the advice you have might run into the same problem for
other file formats.

Comment: Great. Thanks. The problem is indeed with lisp/gnus/mailcap.el. If lines 155-163 are commented out then the problem goes away. It doesn't effect .ps or .djvu files.